# why row insert above 8053 bytes not giving error when it should because max allowed row limit is 8060

Tags: sql-server-2008

I created the below mentioned table -

```
create table abc(name varchar(max),comments varchar(max))

insert into abc
values(replicate('a',8000),replicate('b',8000))
```

The above row insert should fail because it exceeds the max row size limit which is 8053. But it does not.

Comment: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19251004/60188). Basically, `nvarchar(max)` files do not count towards row size limits.

Comment: Since a `varchar(max)` is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) to allow sizes up to 2GB, how could you believe that the 8060 byte limit could apply to them?

Comment: Values a,b are implicitly converted to varchar(8000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when string declared as VARCHAR(max) exceeds 8000 bytes string is moved into LOB_Data from IN_ROW_DATA. IN_ROW_DATA only stores the pointers so that is why error was not showing up because there is still lots of space left.