# How is Oracle able to achieve 1000 columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I am trying to copy what salesforce did in their database architecture. Basically, they have a single oracle table with a thousand varchar(max) columns. They store all the customer data in this table. I am trying to accomplish the same thing with SQL Server. However, I am only able to get 308 varchar(max) fields in SQL server. I would like to know how is Oracle able to achieve 1000 column limit. I'd like to do the same thing in sql server.

Comment: SQL Server supports 1,024 columns in a non-wide table and 30,000 in a wide table. Are you receiving an error message when creating 309+ columns?

Comment: That sounds like a nightmare to maintain!

Comment: @JonathonOgden yes, I am receiving an error. I can successfully create the table but I get an error when I try to insert data.  `Cannot create a row of size 8164 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.`

Comment: That's the bytes per row capacity, not column capacity. Recommend reviewing: [max-row-size-in-sql-server-2012-with-varcharmax-fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251004/max-row-size-in-sql-server-2012-with-varcharmax-fields)

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Just because salesforce has a 1000*varchar2(max) architecture doesn't mean it's a good idea... just saying :)

Answer (score 1):

A `VARCHAR(MAX)` field can hold GB's of information... but the max row size is 8060 bytes, so how does that add up? Well it doesn't store the 2GB in the row, it stores a 24 byte pointer instead. Those pointers are adding up to exceed your row size limit.

You could split the table out into multiple tables with fewer columns, but I don't think there is a way to override this limitation.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, a thousand columns seems more trouble than its worth.  Perhaps you could take a more normalized approach.

For example, I have an Object Def table which is linked to an Extended Properties table.  The XP table is linked to the OD and has fields XP-ITEM, XP-VALUE, XP-LM-UTC, and XP-LM-Usr.  This structure allows any object to have any number of extended properties ... standard and/or non-standard.

The image below may give you a better visualization.

[image]

Just a couple of notes:

1) This is not for high volume transactional data i.e. Daily Loan Balances

2) Each Item ID can be linked back to an object which has it's own properties like Pick Lists, Excel Formats, etc.

3) Once can see the entire history of edits (who, what, and when)