# Change NVARCHAR to VARCHAR column data type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

When trying to change column from NVARCHAR(max) to VARCHAR(max) I'm getting error:

> Cannot create a row of size 8063 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of  8060.

This is correct because of different storage needed to store unicode characters. But is there any way to force SQL Server to make this conversion?

**EDIT**: Table definition and alter command:

```
CREATE TABLE [Descriptions](
    [SerialNo] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [LanguageCode] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [Note] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](2000) NOT NULL,
    [StoreId] [varchar](3) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [UK_Descriptions] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [SerialNo] ASC,
    [LanguageCode] ASC,
    [StoreId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

-- Alter column:
ALTER TABLE [Descriptions]  ALTER COLUMN [Note] varchar(max) NOT null;
```

Comment: Both `nvarchar(max)` and `varchar(max)` can be stored off-page, so they only contribute a pointer to the the row size limit.  There must be something else going on here, could you post the table definition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Max Row Size in SQL Server 2012 with varchar(max) fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251004/max-row-size-in-sql-server-2012-with-varcharmax-fields)

Comment: or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905934

Comment: That's weird.  Have you tried G.Nader's suggestion: create a new table with the desired definition, copy your data over, drop the old table, and rename the new one?

Comment: @Andomar I will need to try if there is no simpler solution

Answer (score 3):

Try to empty your table first then do the change because it seems that a row store the existing data which over its limit. Take your data out, do your change then re-insert the data.

Comment: How could a row store existing data over its limit?

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't move data out of a row when you make this type if change. It's a very rare situation, you're unlucky.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @H nvarchar(max) = N'ESŐNAP' -- rainy day in Hungarian
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max),@H)

result:
ESONAP
```