# Do SQL Server inline queries create temp tables under the hood

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

Recently I faced an issue where I was hitting the 8060 row limit while executing a dynamic SELECT INTO #TempTable ... query. This temp table in turn was used in a larger JOIN and a PIVOT operation. As I was getting the row limit issue I added the SELECT query as an inline query in the larger query (both are dynamic SQL queries) but still got the issue of 8060 row limit, so wondering if inline queries create temp or some other kind of tables under the hood during execution.

The error I was seeing is given below,

> "Cannot create a row of size XXXX which is greater than the allowable
>   maximum row size of 8060"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server can employ a technique called [Spooling](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2013/06/11/spooling-in-sql-execution-plans.aspx) wherein it creates a structure *similar to* a temp table within tempdb.

It will do this, in general, where it has an intermediate result that it needs to use more than once and it believes that the cost of storing and retrieving this data will be lower than the cost of re-generating the intermediate result.

You *may* be able to identify that this is happening by generating an `Estimated Execution Plan` for your query. Unfortunately, there's no guarantee that the estimated plans will be identical to the actual plans that the query generates.

Comment: It was Spooling and the sad part is it cannot be turned off :(

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this is a clear pointer that something is wrong with your database / table design.

Can you add the query you are trying to run to your post?

[More information about this particular error can also be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905934/cannot-create-a-row-of-size-8937-which-is-greater-than-the-allowable-maximum-of).

Comment: It isn't necessarily a clear pointer that something is wrong with the database or table design. It's usually a clear pointer that something can be improved in your queries. Check @Damien_The_Unbeliever 's answer.

Comment: You are correct that the problem most likely exists within the query itself. 

But I am referring to the fact that in the majority of the cases I've witnessed, the query has become bloated and messy, because the database developer needs to use strange and complicated constructs to make up for sub-optimal table design throughout the database(s).

Because the OP is referring to a large join and pivot operation, but didn't include an actual query, I'm assuming this is the case here.

Comment: Also, I don't think that the spooler operation you witness in an execution plan, has anything to do with the error that OP is getting.

OP should post the actual query in order for us to give an adequate answer, instead of all of us guessing about what might be causing this problem.

Comment: While I appreciate your thoughts on this I cannot post the query  due to the nature of my work, but can only state its part of a dynamic column report generated so it has no bearing on the underlying tables or the design.